# Passing a string containing HTML as a http get parameter how to URL-encode it

Tags: c++, qt

I currently have a small Html document present in a QString that I would like to pass over as parameter to a http get method - the problem is I am not sure how to url encode that method.
I wanted to know if there is a method that would adjust the string so it becomes safe to pass to a http get method as a parameter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that should work with `QUrlQuery`

```
QUrlQuery query;
query.addQueryItem("yourKey", yourHtmlText);

QUrl url = ....;
url.setQuery(query);
```

Comment: That mechanism does not take care of ; or # in the url string.

Comment: If the `addQueryItem` does not escape all characters, yuo might have to pass `yourHtmlText.toHtmlEscaped()` or try `QUrl::toPercentEncoding()`